# How to "nest" ggplot's scales/aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with two naturally "nested" variables, say, `country` and `city`, where cities belong to a country. I want ggplot to map `country` to the color aesthetic and, for each country, I want it to map `city` to the shape, but **reusing the shapes when changing between countries**. That is, I want the aesthetics to be "nested" as well, in some sense.

This won't work:

```r
aes(color = country, shape = city)
```

because it tries to set a unique shape for each city, no matter the country. However, I want to *allow repeated shapes if the state is different*, since the different color will prevent ambiguity.

I know setting the scales manually will do it, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution, something like:

```r
# I want something like `nested_aes` below:
aes(color = country, shape = nested_aes(country, city))
```

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you expecting from the guide/legend? Do you want the shapes annotated with the city names? In that case, what advantage would it give over labelling each point with text city names? If you don't need the city names in the guide/legend, you could just `split()` your data by country, `as.numeric(droplevels(city))` in a `lapply()` loop and `do.call(rbind, splitted_data)` everything back together, and use `aes(shape = as.factor(city))` to interpret the relevelled cities as factor again.